# How to check whether user is in pwa or browser

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I need to hide an element when user is in pwa. I tried like,

manifest.json

`"start_url": "/?mode=standalone"`

js

```
const url = new URL(window.location.href);
  if(url.searchParams.get('mode')==='standalone') {
    document.getElementsByClassName("pwa").style.display="none";
  }
```

html

`<p class="pwa">Some text</p>`

I get no error in console. and I cant hide the element in pwa. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName("pwa")` returns a `HTMLCollection`. You should iterate the *pwa* elements:

```
Array.from(
    document.getElementsByClassName("pwa")
).forEach((e)=>e.style.display='none')
```

Comment: This works, but I need to replace`if(url.searchParams.get('mode')==='standalone')` with `if(navigator.standalone || window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches)`

Answer (score 2):

you could check in JavaScript using:

```
if (window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches) {
  console.log("This is running as standalone.");
}
```